# How to efficiently extract delimited strings from a data table in R

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data table in R with text columns of colon delimited data.  I want to return a matrix/data table of results where one of the delimited values is returned for each cell.

The code pasted below demonstrates the problem and is a working solution.  However, my actual data table is large (a few thousand rows and columns), and the pasted method takes on the order of a minute or two to complete.

I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to perform this task?  It appears that the `sep2` option in `fread` will be very useful for this problem once implemented.

Thanks!

```
> # Set up data.table
> DT <- data.table(A = c("cat:1:meow", "dog:2:bark", "cow:3:moo"),
                     B = c("dog:3:meow", "dog:4:bark", "frog:3:croak"),
                     C = c("dingo:0:moo", "cat:8:croak", "frog:1:moo"))
> print(DT)

        A            B           C
1: cat:1:meow   dog:3:meow dingo:0:moo
2: dog:2:bark   dog:4:bark cat:8:croak
3: cow:3:moo   frog:3:croak  frog:1:moo

# grab the second delimited value in each cell
> part_index <- 2
> f = function(x) {vapply(t(x), function(x) {unlist(strsplit(x, ":", fixed=T))[part_index]}, character(1))}

> sapply(DT, f)

    A   B   C  
[1,] "1" "3" "0"
[2,] "2" "4" "8"
[3,] "3" "3" "1"
```

Answer (score 4):

**1) sub** Try this:

```
DT[, lapply(.SD, sub, pattern = ".*:(.*):.*", replacement = "\\1")]
```

giving:

```
   A B C
1: 1 3 0
2: 2 4 8
3: 3 3 1
```

**2) fread** or using `fread`:

```
DT[, lapply(.SD, function(x) fread(paste(x, collapse = "\n"))$V2)]
```

**3) matrix** Note that similar code would work with plain character matrix without data.table:

```
m <- as.matrix(DT)

replace(m, TRUE, sub(".*:(.*):.*", "\\1", m))
```

giving:

```
     A   B   C  
[1,] "1" "3" "0"
[2,] "2" "4" "8"
[3,] "3" "3" "1"
```

**3a)** Even simpler (no regular expressions) would be:

```
replace(m, TRUE, read.table(text = m, sep = ":")$V2)
```

**3b)** or using `fread` from data.table:

```
replace(m, TRUE, fread(paste(m, collapse = "\n"))$V2)
```